# "looked at me (adverb) as she did everyone"

Tags: sentence-construction

This sentence looks incomplete to me.

> She looked at me smugly as she did everyone.

I'm not sure why a preposition is missing. Shouldn't it be *She looked at me smugly as she did at everyone*? Is *smugly* in the right place in the sentence?

Comment: It sounds acceptable to me, but it's like the "at" has been removed. It's definitely fine to include the "at." Smugly could be in several different places in the sentence, where it is is fine.

Comment: It's fine. The  optional **at** has been elided.  **Smugly** is in exactly the right place.

Comment: "look at" isn't really analogous to, say, "bark at". Compare the dubious *She barked at me as she did everyone, or *She threw the ball to me as she did everyone. It's the fact that "look at" functions as a unit that it can be replaced in whole by "did".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct as is.

Here, "as" is similar to a pronoun, except that rather than representing a noun, it represents the adverb "smugly". Likewise, "did" here is similar to a pronoun, but represents the verbal phrase "look at". This comes out as: "*...smugly she looked at everyone*", so all meaning is preserved, and the grammar still works.

It could be improved with a comma: "*She looked at me smugly, as she did everyone*", which removes the possible (unfortunate) interpretation of "...***while** she did everyone*". The sentence would also be even easier to parse correctly with an additional "at": "*She looked at me smugly, as she did **at** everyone.*"